# ElasticSearch query to exclude certain results

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I'm trying to write an ElasticSearch query that allows for filtering the results set. The application provides a filter for job titles and also an exclusion filter for the very same job titles. So for example, in the data set bellow, I want to filter for `Engineer`, but also exclude `Software Engineer`. The problem is that now the query also excludes `Principal Software Engineer` and it shoudn't.

Here's the data I'm using:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "email": "chris@example.com",
      "job_title": "Industrial Electrical Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "esther@example.com",
      "job_title": "Chief Revenue Officer"
    },
    {
      "email": "george@example.com",
      "job_title": "Principal Software Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "helena@example.com",
      "job_title": "Software Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "john@example.com",
      "job_title": "Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "judith@example.com",
      "job_title": "Design Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "katy@example.com",
      "job_title": "Software Designer"
    },
    {
      "email": "mark@example.com",
      "job_title": "Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "mary@example.com",
      "job_title": "Mechanical Design Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "tom@example.com",
      "job_title": "Electrical Engineer"
    },
    {
      "email": "tony@example.com",
      "job_title": "Chief Executive Officer"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the ElasticSearch query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "job_title": {
                    "query": "Engineer",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "job_title": "Software Engineer"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `job_title` is of `text` type. Elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for the `text` type field if no analyzer is specified. This will break "Software Engineer" into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "software",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "engineer",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So when querying with `must_not` and match query for `"Software Engineer"`, it will not include any of the results that include either `software` or `engineer`

---

If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add .keyword to the job_title field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after job_title field).

Modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "job_title": {
                    "query": "Engineer",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "job_title.keyword": "Software Engineer"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

If you are using elasticsearch version 7.10 or above, and you want to make the search case insensitive as well as search for the exact term, then you can use the [`case_insensitive` param with the term query.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-field-params)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "job_title": {
                    "query": "Engineer",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "job_title.keyword": {
                    "value": "software engineer",
                    "case_insensitive": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you are using a version below 7.10, then you need to modify your index mapping as shown below, and then reindex the data

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "job_title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try this version with `.keyword` but wasn't receiving any results. After your post I tried again but this time wrote `Software Engineer` instead of `software engineer` like I was doing before and it worked.

Comment: @Cosmin glad this worked for you :-) Can you please accept the answer as well :-)

Comment: @Cosmin it didn't work with small case letter as keyword analyzer looks for exact match and not the analyzed text as that of standard analyzer

Comment: Can this be adjusted somehow to be case insensitive? I'm sure users will always type in lowercase.

Comment: @Cosmin yes you can do that, but for that, you need to change your index mapping. Can you please tell which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: Thank your for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [match phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) in your 'must_not' clause to exclude only the exact phrase 'Software Engineer'.

Comment: I tried that already. The problem with `match_phrase` is that if I want to exclude `Software Engineer` it also excludes `Principal Software Engineer`.

Comment: I think the behavior you describe should happen only for 'phrase_prefix' @Cosmin